# Using pyassimp library in Python

Tags: python, assimp, trimesh

There is too many information out there and I tried most of them. However, I couldn't get assimp working in Python. This is the error that I get :

```
  File "C:\Users\X\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\pyassimp\helper.py", line 234, in search_library
    raise AssimpError("assimp library not found")
pyassimp.errors.AssimpError: assimp library not found
```

I know that I have to include dll file in the current working directory. I found a Assimp64.dll file on the internet and copied it to my working directory. But it didn't work. 
Also tried this suggestion :
https://github.com/assimp/assimp/issues/1438
Still, it didn't work..
I also tried to compile an assimp.dll using cmake but I couldn't manage to do so. How I could solve my problem?
Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First install pyassimp with pip:

```
pip install pyassimp
```

Second you need to download the assimp source from github. CMake is not a compiler, its a builder tool. With it you can build or create Visual Studio project or solution, if you are on Windows. After you created the Visual Studio solution with CMake, open Assimp.sln file in Visual Studio and right click on ALL_BUILD and build it (alternativly choose your build target "Release or Debug"), it will take 4-5 minutes to build and compile. You will get "assimp-vc140-mt.dll", copy this .dll file to your python installation folder to \Lib\site-packages\pyassimp.

And if you are a visual type, here are some videos i created about pyassimp:[Intro to PyAssimp](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NbbfiKOjkHg&list=PL1P11yPQAo7pxWbkX2Hf8uCtA4oXdXBJm)

Comment: Can I use VS2013 to build the assimp?

Comment: Also, build for your python version. With python 64bit, build pyassimp 64 bit, otherwise it might be missing even though you placed it in the proper folder.

Answer (score 0):

Your assimpo-installation for python seems to be broken. YXou do not have to copyx any dlls into your working folder.

What you can do to fix this is just install assimp via pip

```
pip install pyassimp
```

or via its setup:

```
python setup.py install
```

Comment: This is the error that I get : AssimpError: assimp library not found

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu this issue can be solved by 
**sudo apt-get install python-pyassimp**